# Sharing dll in visual studio project templates

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2012, project-template

I am working on multi project templates having one web application, 5 class library projects exported from VS2012.

We have custom framework dll(xxx.dll) thats need to referred in all the 6 project templates.

I would like to have a common folder where i can put xxxx.dll and refer in all the projects, same way we get nuget references by package id.

I went through the link [Packages in Visual Studio Templates](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/packages-in-visual-studio-templates). It has details how to get nuget references in vs templates.

Any suggestion would help.

Comment: I tried adding dll as a to VSIX project as "Add as link" but could not succeed

Comment: "have a common folder where i can put xxxx.dll " is possible and work with no problem check if you have perhaps some mistakes or i didn't understand you

Comment: Lets say that I have some 3rd party dll,which i want to refer in each project of multi project template.I want to have this dll as a part of multi project template and pack it in vsix package.Hope I am clear.